# Is it possible to create a background service that never of the never dies on Android > 10?

Tags: android, service

I know that similar questions have been posted in the past and the most current solution I have found is to use a JobScheduler + wakelock + Foreground Service as explained for example in this excellent article by Roberto Huertas (https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/).

However my doubt is to know if there is a limit for this method. Does it really work that well? What if the App stays in the background for days or even weeks, will it still work?

If the answer to these last questions is no, is it possible to keep a background service on Android > 10 that can keep running for days without stopping?

EDIT 1:
I'm trying to create a real time GPS tracking app (In this case I'm using Firebase). The company and the users who use it, give their consent to be tracked all day long during their activity. This tracking can be stopped if the user disables the option inside the APP.
I have managed to keep the service running in the background using various techniques, but after a few hours Android kills it.

Comment: Related issue ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230369512 Be aware that you probably need to be device owner/MDM even with foreground service to avoid undesired battery saving notices.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.  It's actually less possible than ever.  Background services are now limited to 2 minutes after you exit the foreground.  Foreground services will be kept around for a while, but they won't stick around forever.

The correct answer on Android is to find a way NOT to need a service running at all times.  This is almost always possible, but methods differ depending on what you actually need to do, which you haven't given us any info on.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Gabe Sechan.  I'm trying to create a real time GPS tracking app (In this case I'm using Firebase). The company and the users who use it, give their consent to be tracked all day long during their activity. This tracking can be stopped if the user disables the option inside the APP.
I have managed to keep the service running in the background using various techniques, but after a few hours Android kills it.

Comment: @Adev This is what foreground services are for, which is the same technique that uber/lyft use to keep track of drivers/riders.  Foreground services can still  be killed, but they are much lower on the to kill list than a background service for a non-foreground app.

Comment: I understand, I can't do much more than what I have already accomplished. Apps like uber/lyft effectively do the same thing however I guess they don't face problems where the app stays in the background for more than 8h because they simply reopen the APP at least every 2h. Sounds like I should try to approach my problem from another point of view.